# Fedora 16 don't recognize my wifi adapter

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, fedora

I have installed fedora16 once before and didnt have problems, but second install took me in hours of troubles. Even with installed right drivers, updated kernel and whatever is writen in tutorials in the net, linux just don't recognize my wifi card. The shortkey turn-on combination isn't working and in bios menu its writen that the wifi adapter is enabled.

```
[root@zhivko-fedora ~]# sudo lshw -c network
*-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 10
   serial: 1c:4b:d6:42:28:7b
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192se driverversion=3.3.7-1.fc16.x86_64 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f6000000-f6003fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: p5p1
   version: 03
   serial: 00:26:9e:61:28:8d
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:47 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:f2004000-f2004fff memory:f2000000-f2003fff memory:f2020000-f203ffff
```

What do I need to do to get my adapter recognized and operational?

Comment: It's writen that no one could help me in support sites and linux forums. I'm searching for people who had same problem and find solution to post it in the forum for others with same problem(99% of PC with same adapter and RedHat linux)

Comment: @ZhivkoDraganov: that's no reason to post it on a programming site.

Comment: I know that it will be with minus votes, I don't caree I just want to see if there is someone with same proble, who want to share expirience.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. It's a little bit strange and don't know if it work for all, but I try to help. Using FN + F(1,2,3,4...) is working fine, if it has only one option(like brightness or volume change). But for FN + F1(in my case) for turning of wireless opens window, where I should choose between switching on/of Wifi or Bluetooth. The chispet drivers opening this small UI isn't supported for RedHad, so I installed W7, then intalled chipset drivers and switched the Wifi on. After comming back to Fedora, the wifi adapter was still is previous state(working). Maybe stupid, but working :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using 64 bit version of Fedora, use kmod-r8192se-0019.1207.2010-2.el6.elrepo.x86_64 from ElRepo.
And,
`rpm -ivh kmod-r8192se-0019.1207.2010-2.el6.elrepo.x86_64.rpm`
`modprobe r8192se_pci`

Now, your wireless interface should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but all drivers where installed correctly, I was trying out to start wifi adapter on.